# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data on my Image Uploader

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

Im new here and did not find out my Solution by using Google or StackOverflow. 

My Problem is that i have a Multiple Image Uploader that works with JSON, AJAX and PHP... But while I am programming, i get this Message on the Firefox Console:

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

Witch is related to this line:

```
ajax = function (data) {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest(), uploaded;
    xml.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
        if(this.readyState === 4) {
            if(this.status === 200) {
                uploaded = JSON.parse(this.response); //THIS IS THE ERROR LINE
                if(typeof o.options.finished === "function") {
                    o.options.finished(uploaded);
                }
            }else {
                if(typeof o.options.error === "function") {
                    o.options.error();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I think its because the Array in the Variable "Uploaded" is empty... But it shouldve be filled so far.. Well, here is the PHP Code:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$uploaded = [];
$allowed = ["mp4", "jpg", "png", "jpeg", "doc", "avi"];

$files = $_FILES["file"];

$succedeed = [];
$failed = [];

if (!empty($files)) {
    foreach($files["name"] as $key => $name) {
        if($files["error"][$key] === 0) {

            $temp = $files["tmp_name"][$key];

            $ext = explode(".", $name);
            $ext = strtolower(end($ext));

            $file = $files["tmp_name"][$key] . $ext;


            if(in_array($ext, $allowed) === true && move_uploaded_file($temp, "uploads/{$file}") === true) {
                $succedeed[] = array(
                    "Original Name" => $name,
                    "MD5 Name" => $file
                );
            }else {
                $failed[] = array(
                    "Original Name" => $name
                );

            }   
        }
    }

    if(!empty($_POST["ajax"])) {
        echo json_encode(array(
            "Erfolgreich hochgeladen" => $succedeed,
            "Nicht erfolgreich hochgeladen" => $failed
        ));
    }


}
```

Im very Desperated because of this... :D Hope someone can Help me... ^^

Niggo

Comment: Most browsers have a means of checking the return data for an AJAX request.  Probably the easiest is with the Firebug extension for Firefox, under the 'Console' tab.  This will tell you whether you are receiving data, and will even parse it for display if the response is valid JSON.